# Trigger to fire when a checkbox is updated/inserted to read true

Tags: apex, before-trigger, trigger-oldmap

I have a trigger that i want to fire when a checkbox is set as true:

The conditions of my If statement are as follows:

```
c.DetailsConfirmed__c == true && trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).DetailsConfirmed__c == null
```

This works fine is a record is created and updated to DetailsConfirmed__c =true but if some one sets DetailsConfirmed__c = true when the record is created I get a null reference error.

Is there a way to check and make sure there was an old record first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `oldmap` during an insert trigger.

Your condition should check if the trigger is update before checking the `oldmap`.
Also, your condition must return `true` if the current value is `true` and the trigger is insert.

Try the below code:

```
c.DetailsConfirmed__c == true && ((trigger.isUpdate && trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).DetailsConfirmed__c == null) || trigger.isInsert)
```